# How to compare Dehn Invariants

Tags: geometry, tensor-products, polyhedra

I just learned about tensor products in the context of Hilbert's Third Problem. I think I understand what a tensor product is, at least what it was used for in the Dehn Invariant. However, I get stuck when I want to compare two tensor products (for example the Dehn Invariant of a regular tetrahedron and that of a regular octahedron). In the example, I get $6\sqrt[3]{6\sqrt{2}}\otimes \arccos\left({\frac{1}{3}}\right)$ for the tetrahedron and $8\sqrt[3]{12\sqrt{2}}\otimes \arccos\left({\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}\right)$ for the octahedron. How do I compare the two? Both are in $\mathbb{R}\otimes\mathbb{R}/\pi\mathbb{Q},$ so it isn't obvious if they are actually different. I guess what I am asking is how to actually compute tensor products in the context of Dehn invariants.

Comment: What ring is that tensor product over? $\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: Ok, [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_invariant) makes it clear that it is over $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: I'm ignorant about Dehn invariants, but it seems clear to me that for the two example elements you gave we need to use the fact that if $\cos\alpha=1/\sqrt3$ then by the duplication formula $\cos2\alpha=-1/3$. Hence 
$$\arccos(1/3)=\pi-\arccos(-1/3)=\pi-2\arccos(1/\sqrt3).$$
Therefore in the group $\Bbb{R}/\pi\Bbb{Q}$ we have
$$\arccos(1/3)=-2\arccos(1/\sqrt3).$$

Comment: Writing the first tensor factors in terms of fractional powers of $2$ and $3$ suggests that those two tensors are equal only if $\arccos(1/\sqrt3)$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$, which is not the case (IIRC).

Comment: Blueberry season. Off the air, sorry I couldn't offer any real help :-(

Comment: I don't think $\arccos({-1/3})=2\arccos({1/\sqrt{3}}).$

Comment: If $\cos\alpha=1/\sqrt3$, then $\cos2\alpha=2\cos^2\alpha-1=-1/3$, no?

Comment: yes, sorry. you are correct.

Comment: i just got confused on how you removed the $\pi$ then realized that we are operating in $\mathbb{R}/\pi\mathbb{Q}.$ So yes, this actually solves it. Thank you!